# Shortcut to delete command but keep arguments

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, productivity

When working in terminal I often have sequences of commands like:

```
cat long/path/to/file/xyz.file
nano long/bath/to/file/xyz.file
bash long/path/to/file/xyz.file
```

etc

Usually I hit control + A, right arrow a few times, backspace a few times, then write the new command.

But during the ten seconds I am doing this, I always wonder if there is some magic shortcut that will do this for me.  So my question is...

**Is there a terminal shortcut to delete the command but keep arguments?**

If not, is there a way to write your own shortcuts?

The terminals I use most of the time are Ubuntu and OSX if that matters.

Comment: You can save all the right arrow movements after Ctrl+A with one Alt-D

Comment: single or multiple arguments? on bash shell, you can use `nano !$` or use `Esc+.` shortcut to cycle through last arguments of previous commands

Comment: I would use `^cat^nano`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In many shells, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> will delete from the cursor to the end of the word under the cursor, so you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to delete the first word.

Alternatively, in shells with history manipulation, `!:1-$` will be replaced by all the parameters of the previous command, so you can type your new command followed by that to copy the arguments of the previous command:

```
$ echo Hello sudo rm -rf slash
Hello sudo rm -rf slash

$ printf "%s " !:1-$
Hello sudo rm -rf slash
```

If your commands have single arguments, or if you’re only interested in the last argument, you can shorten this to `!$`; so in your case

```
$ cat long/path/to/file/xyz.file
$ nano !$
$ bash !$
```

Answer (score 1):

I will provide an alternative way besides using `!:1-$` to get all the arguments.

You may use the typo correcting pattern `^strA^strB` to replace `strA` with `strB`. For example, after

`$ cat path/to/file`

You can do:

`$ ^cat^nano`

which will change the first match of `cat` in the previous command and execute that command again. 
Obviously, this trick could be more useful in other cases, like if you want to change a filename in the middle of the previous very long command.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So below is only applicable for bash shell or I am unsure if this works on all the shells.

Lets say you are using your command line argument in every subsequent commands.

`cat long/path/to/file/xyz.file`
So in the next command you want to keep your argument "long/path/to/file/xyz.file" same but want to change your command, this is how you will do it 
`nano !$`
 and in the next subsequent command you will do the same.`bash !$`. So `!$` keeps the last argument of last command as it is. For example 
 `tail -f /var/log/messages`
`somecommand !$` will actually become `somecommand /var/log/messages` and not `somecommand -f /var/log/messages`
 There is yet another feature that lets you keep the last command as it is. For example you want to run last command with sudo privileges. Lets say you ran `tail /var/log/messages` and you don't have permissions to view contents, so instead of writing whole command with sudo you can simply do 
`sudo !!`
bash shell will automatically convert this to 
`sudo tail /var/log/messages`